# SPARQL filter by date not working for DBpedia

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I'm running the following query on [http://dbpedia.org/snorql/](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT+%3Fbirth+%3Fperson+WHERE+%7B+++%0D%0A+++++%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthPlace+dbr%3AParis+.+%0D%0A+++++%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3Fbirth+.++++++%0D%0A+++++FILTER+%28%3Fbirth+%3E+%221900-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%29+.+%0D%0A%7D+LIMIT+1) to get people born in a given city after a certain date:

```
SELECT ?birth ?person WHERE {   
     ?person dbo:birthPlace dbr:Paris . 
     ?person dbo:birthDate ?birth .      
     FILTER (?birth > "1900-01-01"^^xsd:date) . 
} LIMIT 1
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
SPARQL results:
birth                    person
"1752-9-18"^^xsd:date   :Adrien-Marie_Legendre
```

How is this possible given that I'm filtering by dates after 1900-01-01?

Comment: [Try](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT+%3Fbirth+%3Fperson+WHERE+%7B+++%0D%0A+++++%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthPlace+dbr%3AParis+.+%0D%0A+++++%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3Fbirth+.++++++%0D%0A+++++FILTER+%28xsd%3Adate%28%3Fbirth%29+%3E+%221900-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%29+.+%0D%0A%7D+LIMIT+1) `FILTER (xsd:date(?birth) > "1900-01-01"^^xsd:date) .`

Comment: That works. I thought I wouldn't need any additional function or conversion since the dates are in the "YYY-MM-DD"^^xsd:date format.

Comment: Probably the problem is that the date is not of the form `"YYYY-MM-DD"` thus, it's an illegal literal regarding the `xsd:date` literal. One of many data quality problems within the DBpedia dataset ...